# How can I change the color of the JFXHamburger

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

I use the JFoenix Libary to develop a program with JavaFX.
The default color of the JFXHamburger is black but I need white.
I use the SceneBuilder to design the program but I can not find any property where I can change the color.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

TIA.

Comment: Did either link help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help: [How to change the color of the hamburger icon](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/279)

Or this, to change the background: [Change Pane Background](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/controls/JFXHamburger.java)